# How to change the overall Focus color for all the components?

Tags: android, focus, themes

I want to change the focus color which is blue by default to some custom color? What is the simple way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

you want to make a StateListDrawable and set it as the background colour View.setBackgroundResource(R.id.drawable_name): in XML it is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/button_disabled"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/button_pressed"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/button_selected"/>
<item android:state_focussed="true" android:drawable="@color/button_focussed"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/button_transparent"/>
```

the drawables can be defined colours in res/values/colors.xml e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--  buttons -->
    <color name="button_enabled">#88000000</color>
    <color name="button_disabled">#88666666</color>
    <color name="button_pressed">#88ff8800</color>
    <color name="button_selected">#cc0088bb</color>
    <color name="button_focussed">#cc8800bb</color>
    <color name="button_transparent">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

the drawable can be used the same way you would use any other drawable resource